# using if/else statement in html

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am new to building websites, so can anyone please help me?
I want to use an if/else statement in html to display text and some movies on my website. Below I have added my html code, but it sees the if/else statement as a text and not as a code. How can I get this if/else statement to work, using the temperature output from my js code with openweather API?

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type='text/javascript' src='app.js'></script>

            </head>

            <body>
                <input type="text" value="In which city are you?" id="city">
                    <button id="search">Submit</button>
                    <p id="demo"></p>

                    <p>The weather outside is: </p>

                    <div class= "weather">
                        Fill in your location first
                    </div>

                    <p>What will you be making for dinner tonight?</p> 
                    <div class="inspiration">
                        Give me some inspiration!

                        <div class="recipe">        
    if (Math.round(data.main.temp) == null) {
        <p>Fill in your location first</p>
    } else {
        if (Math.round(data.main.temp) < -5) {
            <p> Oh man.. It is way too cold! Stay inside the whole day and have a nice and hot turkey soup. Make sure you don’t freeze </p>
            <iframe width="392" height="220" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SdJfxGo5PQM?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        } else if (Math.round(data.main.temp) === -5 - 5){
            <p>wow look at that weather, it is quite cold.. With those temperatures a chicken and fries curry would be nice don’t you think? </p>
            <iframe width="392" height="220" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PfoOxeTXdXA?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        } else if (Math.round(data.main.temp) === 5 - 15) {
            <p> Today is a good day, don’t you think? Some cheeseburger cups would taste great!</p>
            <iframe width="392" height="220" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/k-2KdH6k0nA?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        } else if (Math.round(data.main.temp) === 15 - 25) {
            <p> With those temperatures it is not a bad idea to have a BBQ! Here is a recipe for hummus to have as a side dish!</p>
            <iframe width="4392" height="220" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XN4aSh-Dj4Y?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        } else if (Math.round(data.main.temp) === 25-35) {
            <p> Damn it's hot! I can hardly think of anything to have for dinner to cool down. </p>
            <p> Just go get some ice cream please. </p>

        } else {
            <p>Those temperatures are insane! Are you in a sauna?</p>
        }
    }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

this is my js code

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search').click(function(){
            var city = $('#city').val();
            console.log(city);
            $.getJSON( "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&units=metric&appid=9334f947893792dcb9b2e2c05ae23eb0", function( data ) {
                $('.weather').html(Math.round(data.main.temp)+ ' degrees Celcius');
            });
        });
        });
```

Comment: JavaScript code needs to be defined inside `<script>` tags otherwise it won’t work.

Comment: Also you cannot just mix html inside your javascript. Please do the minimal amount of research before posting a question here. You cannot just make up how you think a language should work and then post in SO asking why it doesn't.

Comment: before you attempt to interface with an external api, you should learn the basics of javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript code needs to be defined inside `<script>` tags otherwise it won’t work.

Just put this code in the same function below your jQuery code. And create an empty `<div>` tag with any ID in place of the `<p>` and `<iframe>` then populate them with jQuery. Then depending on your condition change its `innerHTML` (using the jQuery function `html()`). Example:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#search').click(function()
    {
        var city = $('#city').val();
        console.log(city);
        $.getJSON( "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&units=metric&appid=9334f947893792dcb9b2e2c05ae23eb0", function( data )
        {
            $('.weather').html(Math.round(data.main.temp)+ ' degrees Celcius');
        });
    });

    if (Math.round(data.main.temp) < -5)
    {
        $("#YOU_CHOSEN_ID").html("<p> Oh man.. It is way too cold! Stay inside the whole day and have a nice and hot turkey soup. Make sure you don’t freeze </p>
        <iframe width='392' height='220' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/SdJfxGo5PQM?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>")
    }
});
```

I used one condition. Add the rest like I did with this one.

If you’re still facing problems let me know so I can help you.